# What is the best way to solder these wires to circuit board?

Tags: connector, soldering, stripboard

What is the best way to solder these stranded wires onto a vero board (strip board)?

I am thinking maybe using some kind of connector instead of just soldering on. It will make things more flexible. I also want it to look semi professional.

If using connectors, what connectors would be the best?

[image: Stranded wires]

Comment: Spring loaded terminal blocks?

Comment: How thick are the cables?

Comment: What's the wire gauge/diameter and the insulation diameter?

Comment: About 22 gauge I think - not exactly sure.  But the strands can easily fit through the holes in a typical strip board.

Comment: "Semi professional" - what does this realistically mean - I've seen wires like this soldered directly to PCBs on "pro" equipment.

Comment: Thanks for responses all. I'm first going to see if terminal blocks work. Otherwise I might just solder it directly to the board as suggested by Andy aka.

Comment: What is it for?

Comment: What's the main issue? vibration/flex or easy disconnect?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If you do want to solder them directly, you can make it more robust (and marginally better looking) by drilling holes wide enough for the wire + insulation to fit snugly, looping the wires through those holes and then soldering them.  This provides strain relief so that the solder joint isn't taking a significant mechanical load.

This is illustrated below, but you can also have the holes closer together, the other way round, etc - whatever's convenient.
[image: Strain relief] Image credit: Windell Oskay, CC-BY

Comment: This technique is one of the allowed methods in the Space Industry, where there is a standard on this in Europe: ECSS-Q-ST-70-08C "Manual soldering of high-reliability electrical connections" (check Figure 9-9).

Answer (score 10):

You could solder 0.1" pitch headers onto the board. Then use crimp terminals on a mating connector.

[Molex KK connectors](http://www.molex.com/molex/products/family?key=kk_254_rpc_connector_system&channel=products&chanName=family&pageTitle=Introduction&parentKey=wire_to_board_connectors) are a common type, but there are many compatibles from other manufacturers. You'll need a suitable crimping tool, but after that investment the costs are low.

[image: http://www.molex.com/molex/products/family?key=kk_254_rpc_connector_system&channel=products&chanName=family&pageTitle=Introduction&parentKey=wire_to_board_connectors]

[image: ehttp://www.molex.com/molex/products/family?key=kk_254_rpc_connector_system&channel=products&chanName=family&pageTitle=Introduction&parentKey=wire_to_board_connectors]

Comment: Very helpful answer. These crimp terminals hold the rubber-layer of the wire. so they are much safer than just ordinary soldering.

Answer (score 6):

Here is why wire-joints often easily cut-off from the board.

[image: wire joint]
**Fig** :   **A.** Why wire easily breaks-off. **Whole mechanical stress on the delicate copper strands.**

**B.** Fastening the **insulating cover** of the wire, with the **substrate** of the board, (or with the insulator of another wire in case of wire-wire connections) using a strong, solid system, reduce the chance of cutoff.

If you could understand why the wires cut-off at joints, you could find-out ways to eliminate this.

**previously mentioned solutions by other users, based upon this way of stress removal.** The grey layer indicates solder.

However, in test gadgets (**not** professional) i use narrowly cut (2mm to 1 cm wide) pieces of paper **tapes** (masking tape) , or tie with **threads** using the **excess holes** of the veroboard

By the way, terminus of the wire is **twisted** before soldering, so that loose strand-ends do-not cause short-circuits.
[image: Image of wire terminus from wikipedia]
Image of wire terminus from wikipedia

Answer (score 5):

You could try Configurable Spring Terminal Blocks from Adafruit Industries http://www.adafruit.com/product/1074 or 2/3 pin- 3.5mm Terminal Blocks http://www.adafruit.com/product/724 that snap together. I have used these on Arduino projects and the work nicely.