# Wire connector with hole only large enough for the conductor and not the insulation jacket

Tags: connector, wire, pcb-assembly

I am trying to find a connector for a PCB that has an aperture sized to allow only the conductor to pass through and not the insulation jacket.

I found a drawing [here, see part B of drawing below](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/129907/what-is-the-best-way-to-solder-these-wires-to-circuit-board) that illustrates basically what I am searching for.

[image: Illustration of conductor passing through an aperture in a board sized to allow the conductor to pass through, but not the insulation jacket (See B).]

Does anyone know the name of this type of connector? The connection of the wire does not have to be solder, but could instead be a spring clamp for example.
Thank you

Comment: There are all kinds of wire-to-board termination products out there. You need to take a look. But the cheap approach that many use is simply glue -- either hot-melt glue (not recommended) or some form of silastic. The key is to prevent any movement of the wire at the vulnerable point you've identified.

Comment: try "eyelet PCB" searching Mr.Google

Comment: @DaveTweed I reworded the question to better fit the rules.

Comment: pass the insulated wire through another hole in the PCB or use a cable tie to attach it to the board